# How can a SSD freeze a notebook's boot screen for half a minute?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, bios

My wife has a Toshiba Satellite C855D-11U and I got an idea that I'll enhance its performance, so I bought a Kingston SUV500 120GB SSD. I put it into the notebook then after power on the TOSHIBA logo was shown for almost one minute. During this time I couldn't do anything but when I pressed the F2 or F12 after one minute, the notebook opened the boot menu / BIOS.

When I put back the original Toshiba HDD, the bootlogo appeared for 1-2 seconds and everything went fine. I noticed that the problem also exist when I don't use any SATA device.

The SATA mode in BIOS is AHCI, the USB Legacy is enabled.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you install an OS on the drive?

Comment: Yes, I did but nothing changed.

Comment: check kingstons website for and drivers or firmware updates

Comment: There's not really much to go on.

Answer (score -1):

How many disks does the notebook has? The motherboard may not be compatible with that SSD, not accepting that processing speed. Also, did you check if the problem persists in other computers?

Try setting the SSD in ide, not AHCI.

I don't know how else I can help you!

Comment: “I don't know how else I can help you!” While your posting is well intentioned, don’t post a comment and a question to a question as an answer. Please earn 50+ rep to comment. This would be very helpful as a comment but not as an answer.

Comment: The notebook has one disk. Meanwhile I checked the Kingston SSD in my computer and didn't detected any problem. Furthermore I put a WD Blue SSD into the Toshiba and there was no problem with that.